# Asymptotic Upper Bounds vs Tight Bounds

Tags: algorithm

I've come across in CLRS (Introduction to Algorithms) a sentence which states 
"Distinguishing asymptotic Upper Bounds from asymptotically tight bounds is standard in the algorithms literature"
While I understand the essence of what the text wants to convey, It would be better understood if I get an example illustrating the difference.

Comment: This may be a better fit for cs.stackexchange.com - and indeed, this answer seems to cover it pretty well: http://cs.stackexchange.com/a/19147/35361

Comment: Clearly understood, thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

O-notation gives us asymptotic upper bound.
Consider a function f(x),
We can define a function g(x), such that f(x) = O(g(x)).
Here g(x) is the asymptotic upper bound of f(x), meaning for all values of x >= c, f(x) grows at the same rate or slower than g(x) as x increases.
Another thing to be noticed is that if h(x) is the asymptotic upper bound of g(x) then it could easily be concluded that h(x) is also the asymptotic upper bound of f(x). After all, if f(x) can only grow at an equal or smaller rate than g(x), it is bound to grow at an equal of smaller rate than h(x) as g(x) cannot grow at any faster than h(x).

Eg. if f(x) = 10x + 2,
g(x) = 12x + 1 and h(x) = 2x^2.

We can safely say that f(x) = O(g(x)), g(x) = O(h(x)) and f(x) = O(h(x)).
Here g(x) is said to be asymptotic tight upper bound and h(x) is said to be the asymptotic upper bound of f(x).